# IndexOutOfRange exception with String.Split

Tags: vb.net

Getting an error on this code which is part of a function to receive a message, it takes the querystring values and splits them or at least is supposed to right now it gives me an index out of range trying to assign the value to paramValue as `string=params(1).ToString` and I am not sure why?

```
Dim QueryString As String() = context.Split("&")
Dim QuerySet As String
Dim Params As String() = Nothing

For Each QuerySet In QueryString
    Params = QuerySet.Split("=")
    Dim ParamKey As String = Params(0).ToString.ToLower
    Dim ParamValue As String = Params(1).ToString
```

Comment: `ToString` is somewhat redundant on a string. Have you used the debugger? What is `context`? Show the value of `QuerySet` when you get the exception.

Comment: Your QuerySet probably doesn't have an equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but won't fit as a comment:

```
For Each QuerySet As String() In context.Split("&"c)
    Dim Params As String() = QuerySet.Split("="c)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some error checking to your code:

```
Dim QueryString As String() = context.Split("&"c)
Dim QuerySet As String
Dim Params As String() = Nothing

For Each QuerySet In QueryString
  If QuerySet.Contains("=") Then 'procede
    Params = QuerySet.Split("="c)
    Dim ParamKey As String = Params(0).ToLower
    Dim ParamValue As String = Params(1)
    'use variables
  End If
Next
```